# Pivot/gather multiple "crossed" values belonging to a common key

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyr

I have some strangely stored time series data.  Two kinds of values, `event` and `foo`, can be observed together for different phenomena `a` and `b`.  The observations are in time `t` and belong to different `category` (those are basically different recordings).

Everything is stored as follows, in a kind of mixed wide format:

```
> tibble(category = c("x", "x", "y", "y"), t = c(1:2, 1:2),
  event_a = c(T, T, F, F), event_b = c(T, F, T, F), 
  foo_a = c(1, 2, 3, 4), foo_b = c(10, 20, 30, 40))

# A tibble: 4 x 6
  category     t event_a event_b foo_a foo_b
  <chr>    <int> <lgl>   <lgl>   <dbl> <dbl>
1 x            1 TRUE    TRUE        1    10
2 x            2 TRUE    FALSE       2    20
3 y            1 FALSE   TRUE        3    30
4 y            2 FALSE   FALSE       4    40
```

Now I want convert it to long format, with the phenomena being used to index the kind of `event` with a `value`, and the `foo` value being matched to them via `a`/`b`:

```
# A tibble: 8 x 5
  category     t event value   foo
  <chr>    <dbl> <chr> <lgl> <dbl>
1 x            1 a     TRUE      1
2 x            1 b     TRUE     10
3 x            2 a     TRUE      2
4 x            2 b     FALSE    20
5 y            1 a     FALSE     3
6 y            1 b     TRUE     30
7 y            2 a     FALSE     4
8 y            2 b     FALSE    40
```

I'm looking for some sort of `tidyr` (or at least `tidyverse`) solution using `gather`/`pivot_long` and friends, but couldn't come up with anything useful, since there are multiple value columns in the result.  I was thinking about a join with the `foo` columns split of, but didn't really succeed, and I'm not really enought in to SQL to know what goes wrong there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a complicated way of solving the problem but it works.
The idea is to solve the multiple columns issue with in two steps, a `pivot_longer` for each of `event_*` and `foo_*`. And `bind_cols` the results. Finally, remove the pattern `'event'` from the new column `event`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 %>%
  dplyr::select(-starts_with('foo')) %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = starts_with('event'),
    names_to = 'event',
    values_to = 'value'
  ) %>%
  bind_cols(
    df1 %>%
    dplyr::select(-starts_with('event')) %>%
    pivot_longer(
      cols = starts_with('foo'),
      values_to = 'foo'
    ) %>%
    dplyr::select(-category, -t, -name)
  ) %>%
  mutate(event = sub('event_', '', event))
## A tibble: 8 x 5
#  category     t event value   foo
#  <chr>    <int> <chr> <lgl> <dbl>
#1 x            1 a     TRUE      1
#2 x            1 b     TRUE     10
#3 x            2 a     TRUE      2
#4 x            2 b     FALSE    20
#5 y            1 a     FALSE     3
#6 y            1 b     TRUE     30
#7 y            2 a     FALSE     4
#8 y            2 b     FALSE    40
```

Comment: This suffices. I overlooked that the order is preserved splitting the data in such a way, and I can just stack them together after separate gathering!